# TypeScript React Component with specific string value parameter is not assignable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a TypeScript react component whose parameter is a specific string value based on an object. However, I am getting the following linting error:

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type "a" | "b" | "c".

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

interface Props {
  id: keyof typeof obj;
}

const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ id }) => <h1>{id}</h1>;

const SampleComponentTwo: React.FC = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {
      Object.keys(obj).map(id => (
        <SampleComponent id={id} />
      ))
    }
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Object.keys` returns `string[]`. So as you map over those keys, each value (`id`) is type `string`. This type is more general than your specific keys of only `"a" | "b" | "c"` since `"d"` and every other possible string value is possible which is not valid props to the `SampleComponent` component.

You can explicitly say `id` is of type `Key` to resolve this issue.

You could do something along these lines:

```js
export const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

type Key = keyof typeof obj;

interface Props {
  id: Key;
}

const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ id }) => <h1>{id}</h1>;

const SampleComponentTwo: React.FC = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {Object.keys(obj).map((id: Key) => (
      <SampleComponent id={id} key={id} />
    ))}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```